# Do I need to add substituions values that I'll provide via CLI to the cloudbuild.yaml file?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-build, docker-build, cloudbuild.yaml

In my `cloudbuild.yaml` file, I'm relying on a value that will be passed through the `builds submit --substitutions=_SERVER_ENV=TEST` command.

This is how I'm referencing it:

**cloudbuild.yaml**

```
steps:
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: [
      "build",
      "--build-arg SERVER_ENV=$_SERVER_ENV",       // <----- IT WILL BE PASSED TO DOCKER --build-arg
      "."
    ]
```

My question is: do I need to add it to my `cloudbuild.yaml` file in the `substitutions` section?

Example:

**cloudbuild.yaml**

```
substitutions:               // DO I NEED TO ADD THIS SECTION?
  - "_SERVER_ENV=TEST"       // GIVEN THE FACT THAT I'LL BE PROVIDING IT THROUGH THE CLI
```

Or can I leave it out and be sure that the builder will look for it the CLI command like:

`builds submit --substitutions=_SERVER_ENV=TEST`

---

**REFERENCES**

[DOC: gcloud builds submit](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit)

[DOC: build config substitutions](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#substitutions)

[DOC: build config - Substituting variable values](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the substitutions part in the `cloudbuild.yaml` part. However, the value will be empty and can break your Build, or worse passes with an unstable status

As you prefer

- Either a build that passes with a default not critical value
- Or a build that passes with an empty value with unknow/untested behavior.